# Как получить текст текущего элемента?

Tags: javascript

Есть ряд вложенных html тегов и надо получить текст только текущего элемента, без текста всех вложенных. Как это сделать?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  <meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Животные
      <ul>
        <li>Млекопитающие
          <ul>
            <li>Коровы</li>
            <li>Ослы</li>
            <li>Собаки</li>
            <li>Тигры</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Другие
          <ul>
            <li>Змеи</li>
            <li>Птицы</li>
            <li>Ящерицы</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Рыбы
      <ul>
        <li>Аквариумные
          <ul>
            <li>Гуппи</li>
            <li>Скалярии</li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>Морские
          <ul>
            <li>Морская форель</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script>

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Нужно получить животное.

Comment: А текст мы должны сами себе на уме придумывать? И даже тот, который вам под задачу не подходит?

Comment: Он уже есть в элементе. Его надо достать

Comment: Вы видимо не поняли мой вопрос. Повторю еще раз, мы гадать должны, что за код, текст, и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

По-быстрому можно так:

```
$(currentEl).clone().children().remove().end().html();
```

Comment: Это гениально!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var tag; //Элемент, содержимое которого без вложенных тегов нужно получить 
var text = '';
for(var i=0; i < tag.childNodes.length; i++)
 if(tag.childNodes[i].nodeType != 1)
  text += tag.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
```

Comment: `tag.childNodes[i].nodeName != 1` всегда будет `true`

Comment: nodeType, конечно

Comment: Лучше сравнивать с `Node.TEXT_NODE` чтобы не захватить комментарии например

Comment: Ну я ж не знаю - может, комментарии тоже нужны

Comment: Комментарии не входят в текст, и в обычном виде не отображаются

Comment: Ну если комментарии не нужны - тогда да. Лучше TEXT_NODE